# xib file doesn't appear mobile layout in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to make autolayout I can't choose the iPhone model to work on it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No you can not choose different models as we can do in storyboard. But you can set custom width (according to different devices) and height (as you want) so you will fill same like iPhone models.